Create tidy data from untidy grouped rows
I have data in semi-long/tidy format that I need to convert to a fully tidy format. The data is patterned, but not consistently, so solution can't be based only on repetition of pattern.
The rows are linked by a major grouping factor (Material), and the subgroups are only linked by position.
The solution feels like either:

a combination of pivot_wider and pivot_longer
use of lead and lag from dplyr

The raw data is structured like this:

Desired output:

And the raw data dput:
> dput(df)
structure(list(Material = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", 
"M1", "M2", "M2", "M2"), Material_Group = c("A", "B", "B", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B"), Desc = c("Part 1", "Sub 1", 
"Sub 2", "Part 2", "Sub 1", "Sub 2", "Sub 4", "Part 3", "Sub 2", 
"Sub 6"), Qty = c(0.25, 0.2, 0.1, 0.75, 0.15, 0.25, 0.3, 1, 0.4, 
0.6)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


This looks well suited for dplyr::reframe() -- transform each group to an arbitrary number of rows.
For proper grouping we'd first need to create a group indicator, from example data we could use Material_Group values or detect some pattern / substring from Desc that marks group starts, then cumsum() those occurrences. There's a good chance that it's not that straightforward with your actual dataset, but the idea should still apply.
With added part_grp the frame looks like:
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df |>
  mutate(part_grp = str_starts(Desc, fixed("Part")) |> cumsum())
#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>    Material Material_Group Desc     Qty part_grp
#>    <chr>    <chr>          <chr>  <dbl>    <int>
#>  1 M1       A              Part 1  0.25        1
#>  2 M1       B              Sub 1   0.2         1
#>  3 M1       B              Sub 2   0.1         1
#>  4 M1       A              Part 2  0.75        2
#>  5 M1       B              Sub 1   0.15        2
#>  6 M1       B              Sub 2   0.25        2
#>  7 M1       B              Sub 4   0.3         2
#>  8 M2       A              Part 3  1           3
#>  9 M2       B              Sub 2   0.4         3
#> 10 M2       B              Sub 6   0.6         3

From there we can build part groups and reframe each group, selecting either first values (vectors of length 1 will be recycled) or all but first values:
df |>
  mutate(part_grp = str_starts(Desc, fixed("Part")) |>  cumsum()) |> 
  group_by(Material, part_grp) |> 
  reframe(
    Material_Group_Part = Material_Group[1],
    Desc_P = Desc[1],
    Qty_P = Qty[1],
    Material_Group_Sub = Material_Group[-1],
    Desc_S = Desc[-1],
    Qty_S = Qty[-1]
  )
#> # A tibble: 7 × 8
#>   Material part_grp Material_Group_Part Desc_P Qty_P Material_Group_Sub Desc_S Qty_S
#>   <chr>       <int> <chr>               <chr>  <dbl> <chr>              <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 M1              1 A                   Part 1  0.25 B                  Sub 1   0.2 
#> 2 M1              1 A                   Part 1  0.25 B                  Sub 2   0.1 
#> 3 M1              2 A                   Part 2  0.75 B                  Sub 1   0.15
#> 4 M1              2 A                   Part 2  0.75 B                  Sub 2   0.25
#> 5 M1              2 A                   Part 2  0.75 B                  Sub 4   0.3 
#> 6 M2              3 A                   Part 3  1    B                  Sub 2   0.4 
#> 7 M2              3 A                   Part 3  1    B                  Sub 6   0.6

Example data:
df <- structure(list(Material = c("M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", "M1", 
"M1", "M2", "M2", "M2"), Material_Group = c("A", "B", "B", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B"), Desc = c("Part 1", "Sub 1", 
"Sub 2", "Part 2", "Sub 1", "Sub 2", "Sub 4", "Part 3", "Sub 2", 
"Sub 6"), Qty = c(0.25, 0.2, 0.1, 0.75, 0.15, 0.25, 0.3, 1, 0.4, 
0.6)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))


This works beautifully. I can use the [1] and [-1] to get the results I need. But what exactly is that doing? Why use [-1] instead of [2]? The index is grabbing the values of the group level, but how does it do this?
Is it from group_by(Material, part_grp) where Material = 1 and part_grp=2 and/or part_grp=-1?

Negative indices are used to drop item(s),  you can play around with this example: (abc <- LETTERS[1:3]); abc[1]; abc[-1].  Your part group lenghts are 3, 4, & 3., first records of every group hold  Part  ( hence Material_Group[1]), all the rest are for Sub (all the rest, like everything excluding index 1, hence Material_Group[-1]. With [2] you'd only get a single element, with [-1] you'd get a vector of lenght n-1. I somehow believe the confusing yet important part here might be recycling, so perhaps  data.frame(first = abc[1], the_rest = abc[-1])  is more helpful example.
